# Unknown file system, unable to boot from live cd

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grubrescue

Facts are,

I used to have a dual boot linux and windows 7.

Tried to make grub handle bootloader, messed it up, nothing works now.

I get grub rescue right from the off. No way I can boot into any thing.

I get unknown filesystem followed by grub rescue, when trying to load a live media.

Grub rescue is non-programmable as far as my skills go always returns unknown filesystem.

Craft is, Acer AIO z5710, windows 7 pre-installed sh***e.

Can someone PLEASE give a second hand insight as to what may or may not be going on?

Comment: what really bothers me is why does grub rescue handles the live media and onward ?!?

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple, you obvoiusly wrecked your bootloader big time. How you did it, I don't know, but I can give you directions how to fix it.

Get an Ubuntu live CD an chroot into your system.

And yes, I strongly suggest you check, how to boot another device, like the DVD-rom.
In most BIOSes you press something like F5 or F8, or ESC, ENTER.

Chroot means, you mount your hdd partitions to the loaded live cd session using your own folder e.g. like /mnttmp.

You can do this like this...

Open up a Terminal and become root

```
sudo -i
```

Create a mountpoint

```
mkdir /mnttmp
```

Mount your hdd root fs to the new mount point

```
mount -t <fstype> /dev/<root partition> /mnttmp
```

If you have other partitions then that, mount those too AFTER you mounted the root partition, like so

```
mkdir /mnttmp/<home or else partition>
mount -t <fstype> /dev/<home or else partition> /mnttmp/<home or else mount point>
```

Once your finished you need to mount /proc /sys /dev to chroot

```
mount -o bind /proc /mnttmp/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnttmp/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnttmp/pts
mount -o bind /sys /mnttmp/sys
```

Then chroot in your old Ubuntu-System

```
chroot /mnttmp
```

With this you can regain access to your running system. From here you can try to fix your grub mistake, or just reinstall grub from the system.

**This should bring back Ubuntu as a loadable option in your grub.**

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

And from there you can ask your next question... How do i add my Windows System to my grub list.

HTH,

s1mmel

Comment: I will try to do it and will post the information back,here!

Comment: Hope you don't mind me asking but what sort of live cd do you have in mind? An ubuntu or a windows?

Comment: Ubuntu of course, if you are more familiar with windows, you could also try it from there and reinstall the windows boot loader. U need to fix it anyhow ^^ to get both back.

Comment: I updated my answer so you know how to reinstall the grubloader to the bootsector of your hdd. And sorry for the late answer I had work to do :/